# How to display data from a model from a Yii 1.1 layout file?

Tags: layout, yii, model

I'd like to have the layout reflect some data from a model. However, the *render* method from the *CController* class passes the structured data only to the view file, while the layout file only gets the rendered view passed.

So, how to best have the layout display data from a model?

Two possibilities come to mind:

1. Make Yii's layout file a no-op, mimicking layout logic manually from the view.
2. Override *CController*'s *render* method in its subclass.

I'm not so happy with either variant, so maybe someone has a cleaner idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to define a public variable in your controller class, something like:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
    public $test = 'foo';
    ....
```

That value can then be accessed within a layout:

```
echo $this->test;
```

And manipulated in an action:

```
public function actionMyaction(){
    $this->test = "bar";
    ...
```

Obviously it's not ideal if you have many variables that you need to use in a layout. One solution is to use an array of parameters. Alternatively you could look at making your layout more minimal and using `CWidget` to create reusable components for use inside your views.

For example, you obviously wouldn't want to have the code for your main navigation duplicated inside every view, so the obvious solution is to have in the layout, but if it becomes inconvenient to handle the data you could have an instance of a widget that renders out the navigation inside each view (and you can pass data to the `CWidget` class) something like:

```
$this->widget("MainNavigation",array("params"=>$params));
```